# How do I construct a javascript date using a 'day of the year (0 - 365)'?

Tags: javascript, date

I would like to construct a Javascript date using the following pieces of information: a year ('2017') and a day of the year (0-365). How can I do this in Javascript?

Comment: What have you actually tried?

Comment: If nothing else, may I suggest: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date Just FYI, that site is a great reference to check before posting obscure questions like this. TBH, there's several ways to achieve what you ask, which is why I asked what I did. I'm not trying to be mean, it just doesn't appear you've put any effort into figuring this out.

Comment: Also FYI, you could use something like [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/day-of-year/) to do it, if you don't mind adding a library. I have a [similar library](https://github.com/JDMcKinstry/JavaScriptDateFormat), but it's only for getting date formats, not setting dates.